# pip -U -r requirements.txt with a URL keeps reinstalling

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm using a beta version of Django which the download page suggests to use a URL.

The `requirements.txt` entry is simply the URL:

```
https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7b3/tarball/
```

When I run `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` it always reinstalls Django. Is there a way to specify the version in the requirements.txt line, e.g. `...tarball/#egg=Django==1.7b3`?

I prefer to be at the latest version of each package when developing, so I use `-U`.

Maybe there is a better way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try adding one of these lines into your requirements.txt

```
-e https://github.com/django/django.git#egg=django
```

Also point to specific commit

```
-e https://github.com/django/django.git@b8d255071ead897cf68120cd2fae7c91326ca2cc#egg=django
```

or tag

```
-e git+https://github.com/django/django.git@1.7b3
```

Read the [pip's documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format) there's a lot of other examples

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know of this possibility, but I was trying to get pip to be more intelligent about tgz's.

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba Did you ever find a way to do what you want with tarballs?

Comment: @Flimm No sorry, I ended up resorting to use a specific git commit.